# Is it possible to determine if a particular arithmetic operation has caused an overflow

Tags: javascript, math

*I've a feeling that this might not be possible, but in case any one has any ideas, it would be of great help.*
For any floating point arithmetic operation, is it possible to determine that the operation caused a precision loss. e.g if i calculate z = x/y, I want to determine if z has the exact value or if some precision has been lost during the operation.

**Why I need this:**
I am doing some mathematical operations using interval arithmetic. If the result is not precise I need to return a range where the exact result lies in the form of [a,b]. Currently for every operation I am assuming a precision loss. If the result is x, I return [previousClosestFPNumber(x), nextClosestFPNumber(x)]. This works flawlessly. However for very complicated equations the range becomes too large. If I can determine that precision has been lost, I can only widen the range in that case.

Comment: can you run it backwards with the result and compare? ex: `c=a/b` can be checked with `c*b==a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're losing precision in the operation `f(x)`, then it should be detectable by applying the inverse operation to the result and seeing if you get back something other than the original value: in mathematical parlance, `f'(f(x)) != x`.

For example, something like:

```
x = y * z
y2 = x / z
if y != y2: precision was lost
```

---

If that turns out not to be suitable, you may want to consider a bignum library where you *don't* lose precision, such as [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) (though I'm sure there would be others around as well).

Comment: +1 cool trick.. However, is it deterministic? Could there be a case when f(x) has a precision loss, but f'(f(x)) still returns x.

Comment: @Rahul: yes, two wrongs can make a right, and sometimes the check will fail but the operation won't. it depends on the operation but generally, if anything, losing precision in the check will make it worse and thus detectable. ex: `var a=1.01, b=1.1, c=a+b; c-b; `

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately the result has to always lie within the range. If I get a false negative, I am screwed. False positives are still ok. Any other tricks up your sleeve?

Comment: @Rahul, plenty more tricks up my sleeve. Unfortunately, they all have to do with how to convince supermodels to date me, rather than detect imprecise results :-)

Comment: you would have to get more specific about the operation.

Comment: I guess this is the best we can do.. Marking this as an answer